# Trouble with a word limit range regular expression

Tags: regex, validation, wordpress

I am using a regular expression to limit words entered in a textbox field to 250-500 words.

```
(((^\s*)*\S+\s+)|(\S+)){250,500}
```

Since I know little to nothing about regular expressions, I had copied it from another website. I get the validation error regardless of how many words are entered.

Here is the page that the form is on, if you wish to try it for yourself:

http://mlknew.timpecoraro.com/dreamers-community/win-a-dream/

The site is running Wordpress with the cforms plugin, thus I can only use regular expressions for validation.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
^\s*(\S+\s+){250,499}\S*$
```

This will first anchor the string to be searched at beginning and end of the string. Then optionally match whitespace (in case the string begins with some). Then match 249-499 repeats of (one or more non-space characters)+(one or more space characters, including linebreaks). Then match an optional chunk of non-space characters in order to get to 500 (but also not fail if the text contains whitespace at the end).

Comment: Still getting the validation errors, regardless of the number of words entered. It may be a problem other than the specific regex entered. . . .

Comment: Figured it out . . . the plugin was stripping out the slashes. Good regex though!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try

`(\w+\s+){250,500}`

using [str-word-count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) would be better if your wordpress hosting have php version superior to 4.3 .

Comment: No, that will match exactly 250 consecutive characters in the "word" class.

Comment: right why don't you split using \s+ regexp and count the number of result ?

Comment: like
$array = preg_split('/\s+/', $subject);
if(count($array)< 250 || count($array)>500){
 echo "bad";
}